# how to save email body into text file in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to copy my inbox email to text file then search **word** in this text file. if this word exist i will use this word to query **email-id** from db finally forward this mail to this email-id.
my problem is i m not able to copy email into text file. msg variable always empty
this my code :

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
    client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "pasword", AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

    // Get the number of messages in the inbox
    int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

    for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
    {
        string msg = client.GetMessage(i).MessagePart.GetBodyAsText().ToString();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\\My File2.log", msg.ToString());
        var body = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"d:\\My File2.log");
        if (body.Contains("cusotmer ID: X"))
        {
            getemailadress();
            sendemail();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question?

Comment: In what way is your code not working?  Describe the problem.

Comment: Why do you want to write the message body to a file and then read it again to search the text. Simply read it from the msg variable and then save it as success or failure.

Comment: @marwen1: You edited the question, but you didn't *add any information*.  Please describe specifically what the problem is.  What is actually failing?  Are you getting an error of some kind?  Unexpected results/behaviors?  When you debug, what specifically happens and what did you expect to happen?

Comment: @david : didn't getting any error my problem is the text file is always empty. my problem hir :string msg = client.GetMessage(i).MessagePart.GetBodyAsText().ToString();

Comment: @marwen1: Is that `msg` variable empty after that line of code?  "My problem is here" doesn't tell us *what the problem **is***.  Be specific.

Comment: @david: yes the problem is msg variable empty after that line of code

Answer (score 0):

could you use this code :
**var mailbody = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(message.RawMessage);**
like this :

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
{
    client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
    client.Authenticate("mymail@gmail.com", "pasword", AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);

    // Get the number of messages in the inbox
    int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();

    for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
    {

string msg = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(client.GetMessage(i).RawMessage);


        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"d:\\My File2.log", msg);
        var body = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"d:\\My File2.log");
        if (body.Contains("cusotmer ID: X"))
        {
            getemailadress();
            sendemail();
        }
    }
}
```

And, advice: stop call .ToString() for already string objects.

And i cannot understand why you trying to save messageBody to a TextFile. Because WriteAllText function will overwrite this file on each loop. 
So you wont find your all message end of this method. You can find only last message body in the textfile. Are you noticed this?

Comment: im  trying to save messageBody to a TextFile because i need to select specific word form this messageBody .

Comment: Still i think you dont need save messageBody to any file. You can find, select or manipulate your messageBody in memory.